# Handle KeyError in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, keyerror

How can i handle `KeyError` with if's? Depending the error, handling the error from a diferrent way.

```
speed_uhc_team = counts_stats['games']['SPEED_UHC']['modes']['team_normal']
speed_uhc_solo = counts_stats['games']['SPEED_UHC']['modes']['solo_normal']
```

What i want is if the key `team_normal` don't exist in the dictionary assign a value of my choice to that key.

But when the key `team_normal` exists, just  assign the key value.

Comment: `if 'team_normal' not in counts_stats['games']['SPEED_UHC']['modes'].keys():`

Comment: i don't understand - you watn to assign a value in both cases. So what's the difference?

Comment: @Psytho if the value don't exist on the dict assign a value of my choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the key is present:

```
if 'team_normal' not in counts_stats['games']['SPEED_UHC']['modes'].keys():
    speed_uhc_team = my_choice_value
    
else:
    speed_uhc_team = counts_stats['games']['SPEED_UHC']['modes']['team_normal']
```

Answer (score 3):

If only the last key can be absent, you can use `get`:

```
speed_uhc_team = counts_stats['games']['SPEED_UHC']['modes'].get('team_normal',
                                                                 default_value)
```

If you want to hangle any key error, you should use a try block:

```
try:
    speed_uhc_team = counts_stats['games']['SPEED_UHC']['modes']['team_normal']
except KeyError:
    speed_uhc_team = default_value
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
d = { "team_solo": True}

if "team_normal" in d:
    print("I found team_normal in d!")

if "team_solo" in d:
    print("I found team_solo in d!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
try:
  speed_uhc_team = counts_stats['games']['SPEED_UHC']['modes']['team_normal']
except KeyError:
  speed_uhc_team = counts_stats['games']['SPEED_UHC']['modes']['other_key']
```